# Null instead of None when interpretting JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

Im trying to post JSON data to a remote host.

When I open the file and use the json.load function from the imported json library it converts all the **null** values to **None**, all the **true** values to **True**, and all the **false** values to **False**, to retain the pythonic dictionary format.

Whereas when I open the file using the read() method it retains the original json values because the entire file is interpreted as a string. This would be fine if the data didn't lose its dictionary-like properties that json.load() would otherwise offer.

I have a hunch that the remote host cannot interpet the converted values, and sends me back a 400 response with a malformed text error.

Is there a function or method for loading JSON data so boolean and none values aren't pythonified? Or maybe something can be done when posting the request data?

```
import requests
import json

session = requests

key='REDACTED'

with open('create.json', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    #DATA = json.load(json_file)
    DATA = json_file.read()

HEADERS={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(key)
    }

URL='https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets'

x = session.post(url=URL,headers=HEADERS,data=DATA)
print(x.status_code)
print(json.loads(x.text))
```

Comment: Have you tried `x.json()`?

Comment: use `session.post(url=URL,headers=HEADERS,json=DATA)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

Yes that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of serialization. Serialization is not a python specific subject as it works similarly in different languages.

The idea is simple. Convert object's in memory representations into a format adequate to a file; usually to later be read back again.

### Python Json Module

The python json module handles serialization and deserialization to/from json format, via the `dumps` and `loads` functions respectively.

Suppose a simple json file `/file.json`

```
{
  "name": "Pedro",
  "awesome": true
}
```

*Note. Values are essentially Javascript like values (hence the JavaScript Object Notation name).*

For this to be in any use in python (ie. `if pedro['awesome']: # do something`) the values most be converted, deserialized, to a python like format.

```py
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    pedro = json.loads(data)     # this deserializes the JSON data

print(pedro)
print(pedro['awesome'] == True)  # this only works because it was deserialized

data = json.dumps(pedro)         # this serializes the python object to JSON
print(data)
```

Running this script yields:

```
{'name': 'Pedro', 'awesome': True}
True
{"name": "Pedro", "awesome": true}
```

Comment: Too bad json had to dump me to make this happen.

Comment: Yes, that works. Based on your answer I've modified the arguments to:

x = session.post(url=URL,headers=HEADERS,data=json.dumps(DATA))